# Identify duplicates records and insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this in this there are duplicate records are there So my requirement is identify the duplicate records and store into another table i.e., Customer_duplicate
and distinct records into one table

Existing query:

```
Create proc usp_store_duplicate_into_table 
as 
begin 
    insert into Customer_Duplicate 
    select * 
    from Customer C 
    group by cid 
    having count(cid) > 1
```

Comment: please post your existing query

Comment: Create proc usp_store_duplicate_into_table
as
begin

insert into Customer_Duplicate 
select * from Customer C 
group by cid 
having count(cid)>1

Comment: please update your question with the query

Comment: you might also want to take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, except that you can't select items that are not in your group by; for example, you could do:

```
insert into Customer_Duplicate 
select cid, count(*)
from Customer C 
group by cid 
having count(cid) > 1
```

Depending on what `Customer_Duplicate` looks like.  If you really need to include all the rows then something like this might work for you:

```
insert into Customer_Duplicate 
select *
from customer c
where c.cid in
(
    select cid
    from Customer
    group by cid 
    having count(cid) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the duplicates, you can use the below code.

```
insert into Customer_Duplicate 
SELECT c.name, c.othercolumns
    (select c.name,c.othercolumns, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY 1) AS rnk
    from Customer C 
    ) AS c
WHERE c.rnk >1;
```

If you want to insert distinct records into another table, you can use the below code.

```
 insert into Customer_Distinct 
    SELECT c.name, c.othercolumns
        (select c.name,c.othercolumns, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY 1) AS rnk
        from Customer C 
        ) AS c
    WHERE c.rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Row_Number()` ranking Function With `Partition By` in SQL Server to Identify Duplicate rows.
In Partition By You can Define numbers of columns That you have to Find duplicate records.
For Example I am Using Name and No, You can Replace it with Your columns name.

```
insert into Customer_Duplicate
SELECT * FROM (
select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME,NO ORDER BY NAME,NO) AS RNK
from Customer C 
) AS d
WHERE rnk > 1
```